# Retrieving the name of the method from which HTTP call was made using an Interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elastic-stack, graylog2

I am using the Spring [ClientHttpRequestInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.html) to capture all outgoing HTTP calls from my applications in order to log the data. In addition to the data that I am already collecting in the interceptor, I want to somehow fetch the name of the function from which the HTTP call originated. So, as an example, if a method called `getStuffFromUrl` is making the HTTP call using the Spring RestTemplate as follows,

```java
public String getStuffFromUrl() {
    ...
    return restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,entity, String.class).getBody();
}
```

when I capture this outbound HTTP call in my interceptor, I want to retrieve the name of the method `getStuffFromUrl` as well. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to modify your HTTP request, one way would be to add a ad-hoc HTTP header for the method name :

```
public String getStuffFromUrl() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("JavaMethod", "getStuffFromUrl");
    entity = new Entity(headers)
    ...
    return restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,entity, String.class).getBody();
}
```

You could then get back the method name and remove the header from within the ClientHttpRequestInterceptor prior the HTTP request is actualy sent out.

```
ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body,
                         ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
                  throws IOException {

    String javaMethodName="Unknown";

    List<String> javaMethodHeader = request.getHeaders().remove("JavaMethod");
    if(javaMethodHeader!=null && javaMethodHeader.size()>0) {
        javaMethodName = javaMethodHeader.get(0);
    }

    log.info("Calling method = "+ javaMethodName);
    execution.execute(request, body);
}
```

*(provided code not tested)*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This would be a good solution in case the modification of HTTP requests was feasible. In my case, it is not, so I found an alternate solution by storing the data in a Request-Scoped-Bean (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes). Alternatively, you could also store this information in a `ThreadLocal` variable and reset it inside the interceptor